Inteliji problem while trying to run a project on WSL
I have an enterprise application that is installed on my linux subsystem, I cloned the repo and then installed java 8 (using this command sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
However on opening the project using Inteliji i get the following message while trying to build the gradle project:
Please, use JDK instead of JRE for Gradle importer. Open Gradle Settings
I have been trying to change some settings but still ended in failure.
Thanks in advance.
I will provide a list of what I have done so far to try to fix it

I tried re-installing the whole subsystem by deleting ubuntu and installing then cloning then installing java 8 again.
Tried uninstalling the java I installed and tried another version
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
I tried installing the JDK on my main OS (windows), of course didn't work.
Trying assigning the path of the jdk on my wsl to the variables $IDEA_JDK and $JAVA_HOME then resetting inteliji

I will provide screenshots of the settings I have in inteliji

Gradle settings

Project structure setting


ubuntu version :
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

... tried another version sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless You were right the first time. But why are you installing such an old version?

Been there, done that, not worth the effort. If you want to develop on WSL your best bet is Visual Code Studio but you will run into problems, I don't remember exactly at the moment. If you want to run something under linux use docker. If you want linux commands on windows use git-bash. WSL is really only good for supporting virtual machines. Opinions may vary.

If you've installed Intellij on windows, the JDK should be there as well. Why "of course that didn't work"? Also, Intellij doesn't read WSL2 environment variables

Yes, come to think of it, why choose a cross-platform language like Java and then complicate things by building stuff on WSL

My company needs our machine to have windows to get its security (active directory) while the application itself NEEDs to be run on a linux subsystem

@OneCricketeer when I did that , I got an error that Inteliji can't run a project on a wsl with a JDK that isn't on the wsl as well

Yes, iirc you need to install a separate JDK on the subsystem

Try downloading JDK 8 (https://www.oracle.com/de/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html) with Windows and then copy it to WSL. Then set this JDK as both Gradle and Project JDK
